# Is it possible to view who edited a lightning page layout

Tags: lightning

Say i go to a ticket, click the gear, hit edit page and....completely nuke it. Is it possible to see who has edited it? I can't seem to find any admin area to view that information, and obviously it doesn't exist under "**lightning pages"**.

Can i pull it from the metadata somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Click on setup -- > search lightning app builder.You can see who last modified by against the lightning page. I hope this is what you were looking for.

[image]